# Extract last line of multiline string

Tags: bash, exif

The output from `exif` looks like this:

```
ExifMnoteCanon: Loading entry 0xcf27 ('(null)')...
ExifMnoteCanon: Loading entry 0x3ca8 ('(null)')...
ExifMnoteCanon: Loading entry 0xf88a ('(null)')...
2013:08:22 18:01:16
```

In my bash script, I store this in a variable:

```
datetime="$(exif --debug --machine-readable --tag=DateTimeOriginal "$file" 2>&1)"
```

I want to extract the last line of this using bash parameter substitution. I thought this would work:

```
datetime="${datetime##*\n}"
```

But the output is then:

```
ull)')...
2013:08:22 18:01:16
```

Why doesn't this work and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use ANSI C style escape sequence, `$'\n'` to indicate newline:

```
% echo "$datetime"       
ExifMnoteCanon: Loading entry 0xcf27 ('(null)')...
ExifMnoteCanon: Loading entry 0x3ca8 ('(null)')...
ExifMnoteCanon: Loading entry 0xf88a ('(null)')...
2013:08:22 18:01:16

% echo "${datetime##*\n}"
ull)')...
2013:08:22 18:01:16

% echo "${datetime##*$'\n'}"
2013:08:22 18:01:16
```

As you can see otherwise `\n` is being treated as literal `n`.

Answer (score 2):

While `$''` is pretty portable these days *(BSD `sh` supports if, for example, though its downstream fork `dash` does not)*, POSIXLY:

```
eval 'printf "%s\n" "${datetime##*"'"$(printf '\n"')}\""
```

...will work, even if it is annoying. I typically keep a newline in an `$nl` variable, though, and so:

```
printf "%s\n" "${datetime##*$nl}"
```

...is far more manageable. And of course you can just do:

```
printf "%s\n" "${datetime##*"
"}"
```

...but it's a little funny looking, maybe.

Answer (score 2):

Alternately, with a recent version of `bash` you could use `mapfile` and process substitution to store `exif` output into an array and then access the last element

```
mapfile -t arr < <(
         exif --debug --machine-readable --tag=DateTimeOriginal "$file" 2>&1)
printf '%s\n' "${arr[@]:(-1)}"
2013:08:22 18:01:16
```

Comment: hmmm... i dont speak french, but planets are cool.